# Doctrine ODM Query Builder Subquery

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, akeneo

I'm using an Akeneo 1.4 system with mongoDB and have several associations for the data. Now I want to query for products with an associationType which has a specific product in it. The mongo data looks like following in the database:

```
"associations": [
{
  "_id": ObjectId("565867d7c6e41f4408d0068f"),
  "associationType": 5,
  "groupIds": [

  ],
  "owner": {
    "$ref": "pim_catalog_product",
    "$id": ObjectId("56560373c6e41f5b688b47d7"),
    "$db": "akeneo_pim"
  },
  "products": [
    {
      "$ref": "pim_catalog_product",
      "$id": ObjectId("56560372c6e41f5b688b4583"),
      "$db": "akeneo_pim"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("565867d7c6e41f4408d00690"),
  "associationType": 6,
  "groupIds": [

  ],
  "owner": {
    "$ref": "pim_catalog_product",
    "$id": ObjectId("56560373c6e41f5b688b47d7"),
    "$db": "akeneo_pim"
  },
  "products": [

  ]
}
]
```

I know how to query for the products array with in:

```
$queryBuilder->addOr(
    $queryBuilder->expr()->field('associations.products.$id')->in(array(new \MongoId($product->getId())))
);
```

But I don´t know how to query only for products with a specific associationType (e.g. 5) AND with the given productId. Can I do something like a subquery in Doctrine ODM? I tried already with multiple QueryBuilder objects but that didn't work.